# opening a file in "a+" mode in python 2.7

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, file-io

Append usually means saying "Start at the end of the file"

"+" is added in the mode parameter in open(filename, [mode], [buffering]) to allow both read and write operations

Now if I use "r+" it means "Start at the beginning and allow both read and write operations"

And for "a+" it should mean "Start at the end and allow both read and write operations" ; But this is not the case. For "a+" it starts at the beginning and allow read write operations.

So this means there is no difference between "r+" and "a+" .

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248020/whats-the-difference-between-r-and-a-when-open-file-in-python

Comment: possible duplicate of [python open built-in function: difference between modes a, a+, w, w+, and r+?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/python-open-built-in-function-difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, `a+`, reads from beginning but writes to the end and `a+` will create the file if it does not exist.

Since opening file in Python is *almost* identical in C you can take a look at [this](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fopen/).