# Python conditional statement based on text file string

Tags: python

Noob question here. I'm scheduling a `cron` job for a Python script for every 2 hours, but I want the script to stop running after 48 hours, which is not a feature of `cron`. To work around this, I'm recording the number of executions at the end of the script in a text file using a tally mark `x` and opening the text file at the beginning of the script to only run if the count is less than `n`.

However, my script seems to always run regardless of the conditions. Here's an example of what I've tried:

```
with open("curl-output.txt", "a+") as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()

    finalrun = "xxxxx"

    if data != finalrun:
        [CURL CODE]

        with open("curl-output.txt", "a") as text_file:
            text_file.write("x")
            text_file.close()
```

I think I'm missing something simple here. Please advise if there is a better way of achieving this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using a tally mark? Can't you just use a number? Have you looked at cPickle to easily store data on disk?

Comment: Can you be a little more clear ? You mention that you append an `x` each time the script is run, so correct me if I am wrong here, but in 48 hours shouldn't the number of `x`'s be 24 ? you are testing the data against 5 `x`'s .

Comment: Have you looked at `curl-output.txt` to make sure that it looks like what you want?

Comment: @Bhargav Yes, it should be 24 `x`s. I've used 5 as an example.

Comment: @Micah Smith Yes, `curl-output.txt` says `xxxxx`, which means the script shouldn't run, but it does.

Comment: You are using a relative path name which means that the script run in cron will open a different file than the script run on the command line. When you manually check `curl-output.txt` are you looking at the right file? You could change the script to write 'y' and see if it shows up.

Comment: As an aside, `if len(data) < 24` would be a safer test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your original code is that you're opening the file in `a+` mode, which seems to set the seek position to the end of the file (try `print(data)` right after you read the file). If you use `r` instead, it works. (I'm not sure that's how it's supposed to be. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13248062/4794109) states it should write at the end, but read from the beginning. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#open) isn't terribly clear).

Some suggestions: Instead of comparing against the `"xxxxx"` string, you could just check the length of the data (`if len(data) < 5`). Or alternatively, as was suggested, use pickle to store a number, which might look like this:

```
import pickle
try:
    with open("curl-output.txt", "rb") as myfile:
        num = pickle.load(myfile)
except FileNotFoundError:
    num = 0

if num < 5:
    do_curl_stuff()
    num += 1
    with open("curl-output.txt", "wb") as myfile:
        pickle.dump(num, myfile)
```

Two more things concerning your original code: You're making the first `with` block bigger than it needs to be. Once you've read the string into `data`, you don't need the file object anymore, so you can remove one level of indentation from everything except `data = myfile.read()`.

Also, you don't need to close `text_file` manually. `with` will do that for you (that's the point).

Comment: I had tried opening the file with `r` and gotten an error, hence the `a+`, but it seems to be working fine now. I removed a level of indentation and the `text_file.close()`. I'm going with `if len(data) < 24:` for now which works smoothly. I will most likely end up using a `+= 1` counter method for more sophistication. I am just trying out different things to learn Python better. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Well there probably is an end of line jump `\n` character which makes that your file will contain something like `xx\n` and not simply `xx`. Probably this is why your condition does not work :)

**EDIT**

What happens if through the python command line you type

```
open('filename.txt', 'r').read() # where filename is the name of your file
```

you will be able to see whether there is an `\n` or not

Comment: For the `\n` to be present it has to be added in the script it self right ?

Comment: @tgdn There doesn't seem to be any `\n` when I open the text file. Is it possible that it is still there?

Comment: You could do `print repr(open('filename.txt', 'r').read())` to see if there are any new lines. But your script doesn't write any and I cant figure out why @tgdn thinks this is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds more for a job scheduling with at command?

See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-job-scheduling/ for different job scheduling mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

The first bug that is immediately obvious to me is that you are appending to the file even if `data == finalrun`. So when `data == finalrun`, you don't run curl but you do append another 'x' to the file. On the next run, `data` will be not equal to `finalrun` again so it will continue to execute the curl code.

The solution is of course to nest the code that appends to the file under the if statement.

Comment: Sorry, that was an editing error. That part is actually nested in the `if` statement. Fixed in original post.

Comment: Ok well at least that won't confuse anyone else anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this condition along with if clause instead.

```
if data.count('x')==24
```

`data` string may contain extraneous data line new line characters. Check `repr(data)` to see if it actually a 24 x's.