# writing groups as strings to file

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am a newbie and would like to extract dates from a txt file and write them to another file. Each date in one line. But I don't get how. I tried append but it won't work and this way it only writes the last date:

```
f = open("Krupp.txt", "r")
contents = f.read()

f.close() #close the file

# finditer
# finds all Dates and shows them in a List (Montag, 15. März 2013)
for m in re.finditer("(Montag|Dienstag|Mittwoch|Donnerstag|Freitag|Samstag|Sonnabend|Sonntag)(, )([123][0-9]|[1-9])(. )(Januar|Februar|März|April|Mai|Juni|Juli|August|September|Oktober|November|Dezember)( )([0-2][0-9][0-9][0-9])", contents):
    print m.group(0)
    # changed
    with open("testoutput.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(m.group(0))
```

---EDIT---
I changed

```
f.write(contents) # writes contents correctly to file with Umlauts
    f.write(m.group(0))
```

to

```
with open("testoutput.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(m.group(0))
```

Now it writes all Dates to the file, but it writes them directly after another. What do I have to add, if I want them below eachother?

Can anybody help?

best regards

Comment: Please provide more details around this. Provide a sample of what the file looks like. Are you getting anything from your regex match? Furthermore, you are also constantly over-writing the file inside your loop every time you open it in 'write' mode each time. You want to open your file outside of your loop and then write.

Comment: You are simply overwriting your file in every iteration, maybe `open("testoutput.txt", "a")` is what you're looking for. Furthermore, opening and writing to the file on each iteration is very slow - save in to a string and write it once afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is working for me on python 2.7.6

```
#!/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

f = open("Krupp.txt", "r")
contents = f.read()

f.close() #close the file

# finditer
# finds all Dates and shows them in a List (Montag, 15. März 2013)
with open("testoutput.txt", "a+") as f:
    for m in re.finditer("(Montag|Dienstag|Mittwoch|Donnerstag|Freitag|Samstag|Sonnabend|Sonntag)(, )([123][0-9]|[1-9])(. )(Januar|Februar|März|April|Mai|Juni|Juli|August|September|Oktober|November|Dezember)( )([0-2][0-9][0-9][0-9])", contents):
        print m.group(0)
        f.write(m.group(0))
        f.write("\n")
```

The data file I used to test is:

```
Montag, 10. März 2013
Montag, 15. Juni 2013
Freitag, 15. März 2013
Montag, 15. Januar 2013
Dienstag, 15. März 2013
Montag, 15. März 2013
Juli, 15. Februar - incomplete
Juli, 15. Februar 2013
asdasdasdasdasd;lasdjkfas;dlfjk;a fjasl;dfj ;akdfj;askjdfa
Mittwoch, 15. März 2013
test
Mittwoch, 15. Januar 2013
blah
Montag, 15. März 2013
```

Code explanation/changes:

1. I had to add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` for python to get UTF characters in the source
2. `open("testoutput.txt", "a+")` this opens the file in [read+append mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248020/whats-the-difference-between-r-and-a-when-open-file-in-python).
3. You were re-opening the file in every loop which is not suggested! Moved the open before the loop
4. [`with open`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) expression automatically closes the file when out of the context (when `with` block finishes). It is generally more safe since it will also close the file on exceptions and errors
5. `f.write("\n")`: Answers your edit ... adds a new line after each entry

Let me know if you have more questions or you need more explanation

Comment: Thank you very much :) I will probably need a lot of help for further steps

Answer (score 1):

> What do I have to add, if I want them below eachother?

I guess, you mean a linefeed:

`myfile.write("\n")`

Comment: Thank you. I often struggle to find answers, due to missing vocabulary