# Conditionally increase integer count with an if statement in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, global-variables

I'm trying to increase the count of an integer given that an if statement returns true. However, when this program is ran it always prints 0.I want n to increase to 1 the first time the program is ran. To 2 the second time and so on.

I know functions, classes and modules you can use the global command, to go outside it, but this doesn't work with an if statement.

```
n = 0
print(n)

if True:
    n += 1
```

Comment: Remember that Python executes each line of code in order from top to bottom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the comments of the previous answer, do you want something like this:

```
n = 0
while True:
    if True: #Replace True with any other condition you like.
        print(n)
        n+=1
```

**EDIT:**

> *Based on the comments by OP on this answer, what he wants is for the data to persist or in more precise words the variable `n` to persist (Or keep it's new modified value) between multiple runs times.*

So the code for that goes as(Assuming Python3.x):

```
try:
    file = open('count.txt','r')
    n = int(file.read())
    file.close()
except IOError:
    file = open('count.txt','w')
    file.write('1')
    file.close()
    n = 1
print(n)

n += 1

with open('count.txt','w') as file:
    file.write(str(n))
 print("Now the variable n persists and is incremented every time.")
#Do what you want to do further, the value of n will increase every time you run the program
```

***NOTE:***
*There are many methods of object serialization and the above example is one of the simplest, you can use dedicated object serialization modules like `pickle` and many others.*

Comment: this increase the count without me running the program again. I have to exit the IDE to terminate it. I want to be able to increase the count by one each time it's ran. I'm not sure how a while or for loop could be used here. Any additional help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot store a variable between multiple runs of your program in a conventional way, what you need is called **Persisting Data**, for that, you'll have to write the variable n's value to a file and then everytime you run it , it reads the value of n from that file (which is stored on your local drive) , increment it by one and then  write it back again to the file. I'll edit the code for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to work with if statement only. I think you need to put in a function and make to call itself which we would call it recursion.

```
def increment():
    n=0
    if True:
        n+=1
        print(n)
        increment()
increment()
```

Note: in this solution, it would run infinitely.
Also you can use while loop or for loop as well.

Comment: If I need it to run only once each time the program is ran is there a way to do this without using if statements?

Comment: Do you mean if you run the program it will increase the n? I did not get what you mean.

Comment: If I click run on the program the 1st time I want n to increase to 1, and then stop. When I run it the second time I want n to increase to 2, etc.

Comment: I think you can as per this link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012748/how-to-increment-variable-every-time-script-is-run-in-python]

Answer (score -1):

When you rerun a program, all data stored in memory is reset. You need to save the variable somewhere outside of the program, on disk.

for an example see [How to increment variable every time script is run in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012748/how-to-increment-variable-every-time-script-is-run-in-python)

ps. Nowadays you can simply do += with a bool:

```
a = 1
b = True
a += b  # a will be 2
```